# How can I display the data of an array from an API?

Tags: reactjs, api

i'm having a problem displaying the data from the punkbeer API and would appreciate any kind of help

```
import { useEffect, useState, Fragment } from 'react';
import { Switch, Link, Route, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import React from 'react'
import '../Drink/drinks.css';



function Drinks() {
    const [beer, setBeer] = useState('[]');
    const [selectedBeer, setSelectedBeer] = useState("")

    
    const fetchDrinks =  function() {
        fetch(`https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers`)
        .then( function(result)  {
             return result.json() 
        })
        .then(function (data) { 
          setBeer(data)

          data.forEach(beer => {
              <div>
                  <div className="drink-img">
                  <img src="{beer.image_url}"/>


                  </div>
                  <div className="drink-title">
                  <h2>{beer.name}</h2>  </div>
                 
                  <div className="drink-tagline">
                  <h2>{beer.tagline}</h2>  </div>

                  <div className="drink-food">
                  <h2>{beer.food_pairing}</h2>  </div>
              </div>           
        });
        })

        .catch(function () {
        });
        
    } 
    useEffect( function(){
        fetchDrinks();
    }, []);
     return (
        <div className="drink-container">
            <div className="next">
                <p>After you are picked your drink, click next to place your order  </p>
                <Link to="./Order">
              <button className="btn" >Order</button>
              </Link> 
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Drinks
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the return in variable/state.
Example you save in variabe that have name "data"

in view, you can add this

```
{data.map((value,index)=>{
    return(
      <div key={index}>
                  <div className="drink-img">
                  <img src="{value.image_url}"/>


                  </div>
                  <div className="drink-title">
                  <h2>{value.name}</h2>  </div>
                 
                  <div className="drink-tagline">
                  <h2>{value.tagline}</h2>  </div>

                  <div className="drink-food">
                  <h2>{value.food_pairing}</h2>  </div>
              </div>
 )}
)}
```

Comment: hi :-) thank you so much for the reply. Do you mean to save the data.forEach in a const variable and then map over that variable in the return/view?